# Bluetooth PAN on the Pi Zero W

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, raspbian-lite

I have the following problem:
I want to host a webserver on my Pi Zero W and access it over Bluetooth. To achieve this i tried to use PAN as underlying layer.
The first time i followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304163/ip-over-bluetooth-with-raspbian-systems/40579423#40579423).
Most of all worked fine, I could connect to my pi via PAN using my Android phone.
But still some Problems occured:

1. No ip address was set for the pan0 interface on the pi
2. No ip address was set for the bt-pan interface on Android
3. I didn't want to bridge traffic to an other interface

So I wanted static IPs for the interfaces and no bridging. The rest should stay the same. 
For this I intended to change several things:

1. I changed the /etc/network/interfaces config to: `auto pan0
   allow-hotplug pan0
   iface pan0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.2`
2. Set an ip to the interface on Android

Then the real problems started:
I rebooted my pi did the first steps from the post above until i should activate the interface.  But this didn't work because the device 'pan0' couldn't be found.

Do you know what I did wrong or even better, how to fix it?